# ng-keydown event of angularjs ,the value of which key pressed,before displaying the value of key pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to format an input number on key down event,but need to check whether it is a number including a dot(.) and not any other symbols, which I need to verify, before it displays in the input field.

```
<div ng-controller = "MyCtrl1">
<label>Enter a 4 digit number to format:</label>
<input type ="text" ng-model="Number" ng-keydown ="update()" ng-blur ="updated()" maxlength="5"/><br><br>
    <span ng-show ="show">Please enter only numeric value.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: on using ng-keydown event,it first shows the character entered and then the update(),checks for the condition.

Comment: Your example does not have an ng-keydown on it. Any chance you can wire up a fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you should use some special filter directive. The directive bind to keydown event some filter function, which will prevent default event if user type invalid character. Something like that:

```
app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.on('keydown', function (event) {
                if (validCondition) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I make a fiddle, in which I try to create special filter for you (pass only digits and dot) check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jNzcY/

Comment: @user3012939 this method is not perfect, because cut/copy/paste not works. And I forgot to add `tab` character in "whitelist" :) I think, it is not right way to filter characters, which user can (or can't) enter

Comment: You have to question for event.shiftKey to because this let you introduce invalid characters

Comment: Can you please write some unit test for this?Thanks